# When will this execute?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I have a C code:

```
... 
void caller() {
    #define YES 1
    #define NO 0
}
...
```

Will the both `#define` lines execute when `caller` is called/executed, or will they execute at compile-time only.

Comment: Before compile even. At the preprocessor step.

Comment: Yep......I just meant that. So does that mean that the method `caller` is practically empty?

Comment: Preprocessor code doesn't *execute*. Your function body will be the same as `void caller() { }`

Comment: Nothing here executes ever...

Comment: By the way, in C it is a function, not a method.  The empty parameter list means no runtime parameter checking, it should be:  `void caller(void)`.  The situation is different in C++, but you tagged this as C.

Answer (score 3):

The prerpcessor macros don't execute, they are just named fragments of the code which will be replaced by the preprocessor to theirs content if you use them. Read more about preprocessor macros [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html).

So, after preprocessing, your code will be:

```
void caller() {
}
```

Let assume you use the `YES` macro after you `#define` it:

```
#define YES 1
#define NO 0

void caller() {
    printf("My answer is: %d", YES);
}
```

After preprocessing the code above will be the following:

```
void caller() {
    printf("My answer is: %d", 1);
}
```