# array defined in header file and unknown in c file

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, undefined, microcontroller, opendiff

I writing code for microcontroller and the program look like this, 
this is not the real program, it is just an example of it to present the problem.

I wanted to show that if I point to a place in memory and define the pointer in the header file, I cant call to the defined array in source file.

**test.h:**

```
#define arr * (BYTE *)(0X10000);

int function(int i);
```

**test.c:**

```
#include "test.h"

int function(int i){
   arr[5] = 1; 
}
```

and the problem is:
`undefined identifier "arr"`

How could it be that it can't recognize it?

Comment: What is this? Makes no sense to me...what's the end target?

Comment: Do you want to allocate array at any specific location in memory?

Comment: A semicolon at the end of the macro... hmmm...

Comment: The code doesn't compile because this code isn't valid C, it is just nonsense.

Comment: @Lundin - Actually, some of the errors seem to be introduced by your edit http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43913542/revisions

Comment: @StoryTeller No I rollbacked to the original nonsense, since that nonsense might be the source of the problem and therefore shouldn't be edited out. Read the whole edit history before meddling, please. Rollback 2 coming up.

Comment: @Lundin - I see. Well, then it seems it's as bad as originally believed.

Comment: Please specify the microcontroller and the compiler you use. Some compilers for microcontroller contains predefined macros for special registers.

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume the `0x10000` is an exact beginning address of a register inside your microcontroller and you wish to write there some bytes. Then I would `#define` my alias as follows:

```
#define MY_REGISTER (BYTE*)((void*)0x10000)
```

In this case you *may* use the `MY_REGISTER` macro as an initializer:

```
BYTE* myRegister = MY_REGISTER;
myRegister[5] = 1;
```

**Note:** the MCU and the compiler are not specified and I have no way to test my answer.

Comment: this is not the real program, it is just an example of the of it the present the problam.
I wanted to show that if if point to a place in memory and define the pointer in the header file, I cant call to the defined array in source file.

Comment: you don't define any variable with `arr`. `arr` is just a macro.

Comment: Preprocessor macros are just named fragments of code, see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43862568/7893951) about that issue. Anyway if you include a header contains a macro there is nothing to prevent you to use it, except the `#undef` directive.

Comment: `#define` does not "define" a variable of any kind. It introduces a preprocessor macro.

Answer (score 0):

Directives have to be in the same line as `#`:

Instead of

```
#
define arr * (BYTE *)(0X10000);
```

and

```
#
include "test.h"
```

use

```
#define arr * (BYTE *)(0X10000);
```

and

```
#include "test.h"
```

(It will resolve just your problem with

> undefined identifier "arr"

but other problems will emerge.)

Comment: I know it shuld be at the same line. it just happened here

Comment: But I didn't get your error about undefined identifier "arr" when I fix these 2 directives. (I got other errors but they contain notes about *"expansion of macro ‘arr’"*, so `arr` is no further considered as an (unknown) identifier.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is your first problem right here, you can't change a constant. Regardless of the bad `#define` and `arr` assigment, you are trying to change the arr which you defined above as a constant.

```
#define arr * (BYTE *)(0X10000) //; - you don't need a semicolon after define
```

Next, you are trying to assign a new value to `arr`, which is a no no:

```
arr[5] = 1; //cannot change a constant
```

You can assign another array though, but you probably didn't want that:

```
 int arr[5];
     arr[5] = 1;
```

However you could do it like this:

```
#undef arr
#define arr 1
```